# ASP.NET Core authenticating with Identity Server JWT and Auth Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, jwt, identityserver4

I can't see the wood for the JWTs here.

**Background:**

I am writing an API service and am planning to front it with a React SPA. I want to secure the APIs using IdentityServer 4. User needs to provide username and password to access a handful of the APIs - GetOrderDetails etc...

**Setup:**

MyService.API Startup.cs (.net 5.0)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        });

    // Identity Server Configuration
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.ApiName = "myservice.api";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5011"; // the address IDS is listening on
        });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .Build());

        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Bearer")
            .Build();
    }); 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict
    });
    app.UseAuthorization(); 
}
```

MyService.API.Controllers OrdersController.cs

```
[Authorize]
public class MyServiceController : ControllerBase 
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("orders/basicOrderDetails/orderId")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBasicOrderDetails([FromRoute] int orderId)
    {
        // this method returns back the some simple information to show on the
        // login screen
        var basicOrderDetails = service.GetBasicOrderDetails(orderId);
        
        return Ok(basicOrderDetails);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("orders/authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate(FromBody] AuthenticateOrderCredentials creds)
    {
        var authenticated = _authenticationManager.Authenticate(creds.Email, creds.Password);
        if(!authenticated)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
        
        var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, orderCredentials.UserEmail) };
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);

        return Ok();
    }
    
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("orders/orderId")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrder(FromRoute] int orderId)
    {
        var orderDetails = service.GetOrderDetails(orderId);

        return Ok(orderDetails);
    }
}
```

**Testing:**

No JWT and no Auth Cookie: I cannot call any method - makes sense.

JWT token and no Auth Cookie: I can call the `GetBasicOrderDetails` api method - makes sense.

JWT Token and no Auth Cookie:  I can still call the `GetOrder` api method - doesn't make sense because I thought it checks `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` - I would expect 401.

JWT token and Auth Cookie (after calling Authenticate): I can call the `GetOrder` api method - is this because of JWT or Cookie?

No JWT and Auth Cookie: I can call `GetOrder` api method - makes sense.

**Question:**

Have I overthunk this? Not sure I understand what I should be doing? My thinking is I need to secure **all** APIs with Identity Server **and** I need to additionally provide an Authentication Cookie in order to access the `GetOrder` api method - is my thinking correct? Is providing just the Authentication Cookie to `GetOrder` sufficient and so that method doesn't need to be protected by Identity Server? If so, why is `GetOrder` returning 200 with no Cookie and with both?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is the use of AddIdentityServerAuthentication(...)

See the content [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/blob/main/README.md) that says 'This library is deprecated and not being maintained anymore'

So it points you to this [blog post](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/07/06/flexible-access-token-validation-in-asp-net-core/) and I would suggest that you just use the AddJwtBearer() instead.

Comment: I'm sorry pardon my naivety. Are you saying IdentityServer is a deprecated library? I can't work out how that prevents Cookie authentication from taking place?

Comment: No, only that method is deprecated. IdentityServer is very alive and kicking.

Comment: In general it is better to put the API as its own service, then it get's much clearer and simpler to reason about and troubleshoot.

Comment: Why do you need an API that accepts both cookies and tokens? usually you want to use tokens only?

Comment: This is the thing I am confused about. I have some APIs which do not require the user to log in to access, such as "GetAllProducts" and then others which do, such as "GetMyOrderDetails". That is why I am thinking I want to secure all APIs with IdentityServer and then issue a cookie after the user logs in so Cookie Auth to access some APIs. Is this the right approach?

Comment: I think you should tokens for the really secret parts and no token at all or just some "secret key" or IP-address whitelisting for for things that is not so secret.  I think trying to combine several things will just make you and everyone confused.